# PlaySoundAtLocation plays sound after some delay

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I’m developing the Pong game to learn Unreal Engine 4.26 using C++.

I use this code in the class’ constructor to load the sound:

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<USoundWave> HitSoundAsset(TEXT("/Game/Effects/pong-paddle.pong-paddle"));
    if (HitSoundAsset.Succeeded())
        HitSound = HitSoundAsset.Object;
```

And in OnHit event this code:

```
void APaddle::OnHit(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit)
{
    if ((OtherActor != nullptr) && (OtherActor != this) && (OtherComp != nullptr))
    {
        if (GEngine) GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Green, FString::Printf(TEXT("Paddle has been hit by: %s"), *OtherActor->GetName()));

        if (ABall* Ball = Cast<ABall>(OtherActor))
        {
            PlayHitSound();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
void APaddle::PlayHitSound()
{
    if (HitSound != nullptr)
    {
        UGameplayStatics::PlaySoundAtLocation(this, HitSound, GetActorLocation());
    }
}
```

But it sounds after the ball has bounced.

The sound starts at 0 and it hasn’t any silent.

[image]

Is there any way to play it immediately?

Comment: That code looks correct.  Does the UE_LOG display immediately or is it also delayed?

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for you comment. I don't know what you mean with UE_LOG but the message from `AddOnScreenDebugMessage` display immediately.